# Invocación de repositorio en test da NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, junit

Estoy realizando una clase de Test para aumentar la cobertura técnica en un caso de uso en un proyecto con SpringBoot. En el mismo utilizo dos repositorios distintos a base de datos, una REDIS y otra Mongo, los cuales están con @Autowired en la implementación del caso de uso.

Ahora mismo lo tengo así:

```
class FindBoxesByIdsCaseImplTest {

  @Mock
  private DataBaseRepository dataBaseRepository;

  @Mock
  private CacheRepository cacheRespository;
```

En el setUp lo tengo así:

```
@BeforeEach
  void setUp() {

    dataBaseRepository = Mockito.mock(DataBaseRepository.class);

    cacheRespository = Mockito.mock(CacheRepository.class);
```

A la hora de ejecutar los test ambos repositorios me dan NullPointerException.

¿A qué puede deberse?

Gracias.

Comment: Sin ver el código completo del test y en qué línea tienes ese NPE, es complicado saber la causa